# C# change string value to be next value in alphabetical order

Tags: c#

So this is what i'm trying to do.  I have a string alphaCode, and what i simply want to do is increase from letter A to letter B.  I did a way that assigned each letter an int and then did int++, but i'm assuming there has to be a better way.

```
string alphaCode = "a"

result = "b"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string GetNextCode(string alphaCode)
{
    Debug.Assert(alphaCode.Length == 1 && Regex.IsMatch(alphaCode, "[a-yA-y]"));

    var next = (char) (alphaCode[0] + 1);
    return next.ToString();
}
```

Assert is there just to communicate intentions - i.e. that I did understand your requirements right. It is even somewhat redundant.

Comment: great example, however if i wanted to start at A and go to b, c , d ,e ,f ect.. how would you handle that ?

Comment: @Mike: What the problem with it? This function will give you next letter in alphabet in the same case as parameter was passed. Notice that "z" is invalid param according to my Assert.

Comment: @recursive: then you need to filter out "z" letter with separate condition. In both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Ivan, never said there was a problem, I actually thought it was really well done.

Comment: @Mike Oh, you just want the result always be lower-case regardless of the input? `var next = (char) (Char.ToLower(alphaCode[0]) + 1);`

Comment: no, i just need to continue the loop until a specific character is found, but i can handle that

Answer (score 3):

If you use a char type you can do it like this:

```
char alphaChar = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
Console.WriteLine(alphaChar++);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about,

```
String sample = "a";
String next = ((char)(sample[0] + 1)).ToString();
```

Converts first character of the string to next following character.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is using ASCII Codes, for achieving this you can simply cast  each character to an int, you can use the following code

```
 string st = "a";
 char c = st[0];
 int x = (int)c;
 x = x + 1;
 c = Convert.ToChar(x);
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to array to pull a character out of a string by index.